# MongoDB watch() aggregation match by field value

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

When I use the `watch()` function on my collection, I am passing a aggregation to filter what comes through. I was able to get `operationType` to work correctly, but I also only want to include documents in which the `city` field is equal to `Vancouver`. The current syntax I am using does not work:

```py
change_stream = client.mydb.mycollection.watch([
    {
        '$match': {
             'operationType': { '$in': ['replace', 'insert'] },
             'fullDocument': {'city': {'$eq': 'Vancouver'} }
         }
    }
])
```

And for reference, this is the what the dictionary that I'm aggregating looks like:

```py
{'_id': {'_data': '825F...E0004'},
 'clusterTime': Timestamp(1595565179, 2),
 'documentKey': {'_id': ObjectId('70fc7871...')},
 'fullDocument': {'_id': ObjectId('70fc7871...'),
                   'city': 'Vancouver',
 'ns': {'coll': 'notification', 'db': 'pipeline'},
 'operationType': 'replace'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I just have to use a dot to access the nested dictionary:

```py
change_stream = client.mydb.mycollection.watch([
    {
        '$match': {
             'operationType': { '$in': ['replace', 'insert'] },
             'fullDocument.city': 'Vancouver' }
         }
    }
])
```